# Python keyboard module cannot write "7"

Tags: python, keyboard

Been working on an NFC-project that reads nfc-tags uid, the uid needs to be sent somehow to chromium in kiosk-mode, either refreshing the page or loading a new html into a container. At this point I har a jQuery that reader keypresses and a python script that reads the nfc-tags writing the uid via keyboard.write(). This works like a charm except for when the uid contains a "7". The char 7 never writes, which seems a bit odd.

When I try `keyboard.write('1234567890', exact=True)` the output is 123456890, thus missing a char in the uid.

```
print(uid)
```

always returns the correct uid.

Anyone care to help?

```
from smartcard.CardType import AnyCardType
from smartcard.CardRequest import CardRequest
from smartcard.util import toHexString
from datetime import date
import keyboard
from time import sleep

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            apdu = [0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]
            #apdu = [0xFF, 0xB0, 0x00, 0x18, 0x04]
            card_request = CardRequest(timeout=None, cardType=AnyCardType(), newcardonly = True)
            card_service = card_request.waitforcard()
            card_service.connection.connect()
            response, sw1, sw2 = card_service.connection.transmit(apdu)
            uid = toHexString(response).replace(" ", "")
            keyboard.write(uid, exact=True)
            print (uid)
        except:
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please add minimum working code.

Comment: Added full code!

Answer (score 0):

```
import keyboard
test = keyboard.write('1234567890', exact=True)

result : test1234567890
```

there should be a problem within the installation of the module try to reinstall it again

Comment: Thanks, tried that a couple of times but no luck. Problem still persists!

Comment: SOLVED; partially anyhow. Reinstalled Ubuntu with english lang and keyboard layout, and now it works. Would like it to work with other languages though.

Comment: yeah i knew that it is gonna work please rate my answer